# Selenium with symfony2

Tags: symfony, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

What's the best practices to use selenium with Sf2 to do functional test? Must I use the selenium1 with selenium Rc, or selenium2 with webdriver?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Behat](http://behat.org/), [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/) and [the Symfony extension for Behat](https://github.com/Behat/Symfony2Extension). This is great stuff that will allow you to conduct your functional tests with many different drivers